# how to import yahoomail contacts to another web application

Tags: api, service, import-contacts

I have a web application where user can create his/her account.I want that user can import email contacts from his/her yahoo account.How can I do that? I thnk I havr to use yahoo API or some services kind of.????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the API and instructions are at http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/